# Correct api access url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am writting apis for mobile app in codeigniter but i don't know how can i access those apis through chrome rest console or as a url for mobile apps.

My structure is like following

-application
  - config
  - controllers
   - v1 (in v1 folder bellow structure contains appapi.php file)
     - appapi.php (My api file which contains functions to be called with url i.e v1\getrecord)
  - models
  - other folders
-database
-other folders

I am not able to access those functions in my appapi.php through url
url will be something like myproject/v1/appapi/function_name

Any one can please tell me about the correct url?

Comment: You could make a url like that with htaccess, but that's pretty slow.  I'd honestly recommend sending the function name as GET data to an index.php (i.e. `myproject/v1/appapi/?f=function_name`), because that's a good practice and it's pretty fast.

Comment: Yea. Your way is much good

Comment: @Scelesto can i do it like this using the way you told me through index.php
i.e myproject/v1/appapi/function_name

Comment: You can use HTACCESS to redirect all nonexistent calls to index.php, but it's perhaps not the best way?